# Webview - how can we come to know, it is already cached or not

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, offline-mode

I am using webview in my application. I need to check whether app is in offline mode. If it is in offline and webview is already cached the url, then i need to show the cached page and if i am offline and the page is not already cached, then i need to error page.
I am using following code below

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB   
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(app.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    if (!isOnline) {
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }
```

Can anybody have idea about this?

Thanks